# Eclipse export libraries with non jar files

Tags: java, eclipse, jar, languagetool

I'm facing a problem I have never had before when exporting my eclipse project with external library. I made a little program with spelling correction and I used the language tool library you can find [here](https://www.languagetool.org/).

I put this library in the build path and correctly imported into my eclipse project. When I ask to export it into a runnable jar, Eclipse exports only the jar files into languageTool library, but this library contains also some txt and xml files. So when I try to launch the application from command line it gives me error because can't find this txt and xml files. I tried to add to my jar archive manually but obviously it doesn't work. How can I fix it?

Thanks for your time and forgive me for my bad english.

Comment: Maybe your problem is answered here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/134691/how-do-i-create-a-jar-file-which-includes-xml-and-html-files

"I just added all the files into my Eclipse project (including the txt, html, xml, etc files).

Then I used Eclipse to File->Export->Jar File->Next Check the "Export Java source files and resources" box.

Done."

Comment: thanks for your quick answer but i need an executable jar and this is not an executable jar file

Comment: Right click project > Runnable Jar File > Package Required Libraries Into Generated JAR > Finish

Comment: this doesn't work. This is what i have done and eclipse will export only the jar files and not the other not jar files inside languagetool